# finding consecutive siblings with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, nokogiri

Here's an easy point for an XPath expert! :)

Document structure:

```
<tokens>
  <token>
    <word>Newt</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Gingrich</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>admires</word><entityType>VERB</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Garry</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Trudeau</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
</tokens>
```

Ignoring the semantic improbability of the document, I want to pull out [["Newt", "Gingrich"], ["Garry", "Trudeau"]], that is: when there are two tokens in a row whose entityTypes are PROPER_NOUN, I want to extract the words from those two tokens.

I've gotten as far as:

```
"//token[entityType='PROPER_NOUN']/following-sibling::token[1][entityType='PROPER_NOUN']"
```

... which gets as far as finding the second of two consecutive PROPER_NOUN tokens, but I'm not sure how to get it to emit the first token along with it.

Some notes:

- I don't mind doing higher-level processing of the NodeSets (e.g. in Ruby / Nokogiri) if that simplifies the problem.
- In the event that there are three or more consecutive PROPER_NOUN tokens (call them A, B, C), ideally I'd like to emit [A, B], [B, C].

### update

Here's my solution using higher-level Ruby functions.  But I'm tired of all those XPath bullies kicking sand in my face, and I'd like to know the way REAL XPath coders do it!

```
def extract(doc)
  names = []
  sentences = doc.xpath("//tokens")
  sentences.each do |sentence| 
    tokens = sentence.xpath("token")
    prev = nil
    tokens.each do |token|
      name = token.xpath("word").text if token.xpath("entityType").text == "PROPER_NOUN"
      names << [prev, name] if (name && prev)
      prev = name
    end
  end
  names
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this in two steps. First step is to select a set of nodes:

```
//token[entityType='PROPER_NOUN' and following-sibling::token[1][entityType='PROPER_NOUN']]
```

This gives you all the `token`s that start a 2-word pair.  Then to get the actual pair, iterate over the node list and extract `./word` and `following-sibling::token[1]/word`

Using XmlStarlet ( http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/ - awesome tool for quick xml manipulation) the command line is

```
xml sel -t -m "//token[entityType='PROPER_NOUN' and following-sibling::token[1][entityType='PROPER_NOUN']]" -v word -o "," -v "following-sibling::token[1]/word" -n /tmp/tok.xml
```

giving

```
Newt,Gingrich
Garry,Trudeau
```

XmlStarlet will also compile that command line to xslt, the relevant bit is

```
  <xsl:for-each select="//token[entityType='PROPER_NOUN' and following-sibling::token[1][entityType='PROPER_NOUN']]">
    <xsl:value-of select="word"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="','"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::token[1]/word"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Using Nokogiri it could look something like:

```ruby
#parse the document
doc = Nokogiri::XML(the_document_string)

#select all tokens that start 2-word pair
pair_starts = doc.xpath '//token[entityType = "PROPER_NOUN" and following-sibling::token[1][entityType = "PROPER_NOUN"]]'

#extract each word and the following one
result = pair_starts.each_with_object([]) do |node, array|
  array << [node.at_xpath('word').text, node.at_xpath('following-sibling::token[1]/word').text]
end
```

Comment: I came up with pretty much the same answer as you, so I added an example using Nokogiri to this answer rather than adding another answer.

Answer (score 1):

**This XPath 1.0 expression**:

```
   /*/token
      [entityType='PROPER_NOUN'
     and
       following-sibling::token[1]/entityType = 'PROPER_NOUN'
      ]
       /word
```

**selects all "first-in-pair noun-words"**

**This XPath expression**:

```
/*/token
  [entityType='PROPER_NOUN'
 and
   preceding-sibling::token[1]/entityType = 'PROPER_NOUN'
  ]
   /word
```

**Selects all "second-in-pair noun-words"**

You'll have to produce the actual pairs taking the kth node of each of the two produced result node-sets.

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
  "/*/token
      [entityType='PROPER_NOUN'
     and
       following-sibling::token[1]/entityType = 'PROPER_NOUN'
      ]
       /word
  "/>
==============
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/*/token
      [entityType='PROPER_NOUN'
     and
       preceding-sibling::token[1]/entityType = 'PROPER_NOUN'
      ]
       /word
  "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**simply evaluates the two XPath expressions and outputs the results** of these two evaluations (using a suitable delimiter to visualize the end of the first result and the start of the second result).

**When applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<tokens>
  <token>
    <word>Newt</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Gingrich</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>admires</word><entityType>VERB</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Garry</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Trudeau</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
</tokens>
```

**the output is**:

```
<word>Newt</word>
<word>Garry</word>
==============
  <word>Gingrich</word>
<word>Trudeau</word>
```

**and the combining (zipping) of the two results** (which you will specify in your favorite PL) is:

```
["Newt", "Gingrich"]
```

and

```
["Garry", "Trudeau"]
```

**When the same transformation is applied on this XML document** (note we now have one tripple):

```
<tokens>
  <token>
    <word>Newt</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Gingrich</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Rep</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>admires</word><entityType>VERB</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Garry</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
  <token>
    <word>Trudeau</word><entityType>PROPER_NOUN</entityType>
  </token>
</tokens>
```

**the result now is**:

```
<word>Newt</word>
<word>Gingrich</word>
<word>Garry</word>
==============
  <word>Gingrich</word>
<word>Rep</word>
<word>Trudeau</word>
```

and zipping the two results produces the correct, wanted final result:

```
["Newt", "Gingrich"],

["Gingrich", "Rep"],
```

and

```
["Garry", "Trudeau"]
```

**Do Note**:

The wanted result *can* be produced using a single XPath 2.0 expression. Do let me know if you are interested in an XPath 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 0):

XPath returns a node or a nodeset, but doesn't return groups. So you have to identify the start of each group, then grab the rest.

```
first = "//token[entityType='PROPER_NOUN' and following-sibling::token[1][entityType='PROPER_NOUN']]/word"
next = "../following-sibling::token[1]/word"

doc.xpath(first).map{|word| [word.text, word.xpath(next).text] }
```

Output:

```
[["Newt", "Gingrich"], ["Garry", "Trudeau"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

XPath alone isn't powerful enough for this task. But it's very easy in XSLT:

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="token" group-adjacent="entityType">
  <xsl:if test="current-grouping-key="PROPER_NOUN">
     <xsl:copy-of select="current-group">
     <xsl:text>====</xsl:text>
  <xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```